# Require.ensure() non-blocking

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd, commonjs

If we have different bundles created by *webpack* and we `require.ensure` something to dynamically *transfer+eval* it at a later point in time, it happens via *jsonPadding* and some webpack js magic. If we have

```
require.ensure([ ], ( require ) => {
    console.log('before...');
    var data = require( './myModule.js' );
    console.log('after...');
  }, 'myModule')
```

`"after..."` will get encountered when that module was entirely transferred and evaluated. If it happens to be that this *chunk* / *module* is pretty big, contains images, css and whatnot, the loading will pretty much lock down a browser while the webpack javascript code unpacks the bundle with all its components.

**Question**: Is there any way to "hook" into that `require` magic? For instance, it would be a dream scenario to have callbacks for:

- *whole file / chunk was transferred*
- *image[1] was evaluated*
- *css[1] was evaluated / style tag was injected*
- *javascript was evaluated*

and so forth, assuming that our transferred bundle contains a lot of data. In general it just bothers me pretty hard to have a nice option to asynchronously transfer whole bundles dynamically, but still have to load that very bundle in full sync / blocking fashion.

Comment: You can lazyload in the background all chunks from `require.ensure`. So when user enters some `require.ensure` chunk it will probably be already loaded. If you thinks this solve your problems I can write an answer.

Comment: Not really. Lazy loading will only autoload a bundle after main-bundles were transferred. The problem of blocking transfer-evaluating will remain.

Comment: So are you looking for a way to plugin to the evaluation of these dependencies. If so, are you wanting the event's before or after they resolve?

Comment: I'm not even sure if that's possible, but it's always good to ask isn't it. In the perfect world there would be several hooks respectively callbacks, where you can decide when each part of the whole bundle gets evaluated. Otherwise we have zero control over long-running blocking processes, which I think are very possible if you really bundle a lot of things together.

Comment: Before I write a supercrazylong answer, have you tried this with webpack2 and System.import. Its promise based and may give you a bit more flexibility in the deferral. (I believe the SystemImportDependencyPlugin in core has a slightly different approach than the `require.ensure`). It can be used the same way instead with `System.import('./path/to/something/).then((module)=>{})`

Comment: I heard about the support of `System.import` but I don't really see how that would help in this instance. Especially because loading an ES6 Module kind of dynamically with `import` doesn't fullfill the same requirements. A webpack bundle which was "precompiled" and concatenated with all its dependencies (css, html, images, fonts) is a different story no?

Comment: At some point, webpack's chunks evaluated all modules contained within at runtime. I don't know if that still happens. Anyway, I made a plugin to disable that behavior. It might be useful in your case. https://github.com/Morhaus/webpack-vendor-chunk-plugin

Comment: Is the `myModule.js` generated dynamically every time or is it static?

Comment: Is the image[1] etc required from within the myModule? And if so, should you really be concerned with the internal module dependencies outside of the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I was confused about the topic myself, so my question was probably not precise enough to get properly answered. However, my misunderstanding on the whole "commonJS dynamic module loading" context was, that `require.ensure()` will just transfer the *Module Code* (respectively the *Chunk* which webpack created) over the wire. After that the transferred *Chunk* which basically is just one big ECMAscript file just sits there in the browser, cached but not evaluated yet. Evaluation of the entire *Chunk* happens only on the actual `require()` call.

Having that said, it is entirely in your hands how you decouple and evaluate the individual parts of a *Module* / *Chunk*. If for example, like in my original question, a module `requires()` in some *CSS Files*, some *Images* and some *HTML*, that all gets asynchronously transferred on the `require.ensure()` call. In which manner you `require()` (and therefore *evaluate*) those parts is entirely up to you and you can decouple those call if necessary yourself.

For instance, a Module looks like this:

**Module1.js**

```
"use strict";
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

document.getElementById( 'foo' ).addEventListener('click', ( event ) => {
    let partCSS = require( 'style/usable!./someCoolCSS.css' ),
        moarCSS = require( 'style/usable!./moarCoolCSS.css' ),
        tmpl    = require( './myTemplate.html' ),
        image1  = require( './foo.jpg' ),
        image2  = require( './bar.png' );
}, false);
```

Of course, all these files are already contained by the Chunk which gets transferred to the client, when some other *Module* calls:

```
require.ensure([ 'Module1.js' ], ( require ) => {
}, 'Module1');
```

This is were my confusion was. So now, we can just play with the `require()` calls within `module1.js` ourself. If we really require a lot of files that way, we could even use a `setTimeout` / `setImmediate` run-away-timer to decouple the synchronous evaluation between each `require()` call if necessary or wanted.

Actually a long answer for a pretty simple story.

**TL;DR:**
"*`require.ensure` transfers a whole chunk over the wire. This chunk contains all files which are part of a `require()` call within the ensured Module. But those files do **not** get automatically evaluated. That happens only when the actual `require()` call is matched at runtime (which is represented by a webpackJSONP call at this point)*"

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed self-answered question. I ran into this issue where I was trying to figure out how to separate the timing between code evaluation and the chunk transferred over the wire. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

> Let me preface by saying I know this might be an 'annoying' answer, because it doesn't answer your question directly but offers an
>   alternative, pragmatic, solution to the browser hanging problem. I
>   used this pattern myself to manage asset loading within the context of
>   a heavy 3D web game.
>
> I'm writing this as an answer and not as a comment so it might serve
>   others who come across the same problem. If this does answer your
>   case, I'll be happy to provide actual code to implement and generify
>   these sort of modules.

If I understand correctly, essentially what you want is a way to break down `MyModule` into discrete components which can be atomically loaded and evaluated within the context of one `require.ensure`, but handle evaluating so that not everything is evaluated in one go resulting in browser hang.

A different way to look at this is to use the `require` and `ensure` methods themselves as the loading/evaluation mechanisms. Consider `MyModule.js`, which is a huge-loading module with the dependencies `Css1, Css2, ... CssN` as well as `JS1, JS2, ... JSN` and images.

My suggestion is to break it down into `SuperMyModule.js` which requires `MyModuleLogic.js` as well as all the CSS, images and JS.

Node, in `SuperMyModule.js` you could do:

```
let myModuleLogic = require("myModuleLogic");
console.log('JS was evaluated');

require.ensure(['image1.png'], ( require ) => {
    let data = require( './images1.png' );
    console.log('image[1] was evaluated');
    // register that resource was evaluated/fire event
})
require.ensure(['style1.css'], ( require ) => {
    let data = require( './style1.css' );
    console.log('css[1] was evaluated');
    // register that resource was evaluated/fire event
})

//after all resources evaluated/fire callback or event
```

Then in your original file, like you requested:

```
require.ensure([ ], ( require ) => {
    console.log('before...');
    let myModule = require( './superMyModule.js' );
    console.log('after...');
  })
```

And if you set up your module instance as an event emitter possibly hook into the loading of resources like so:

```
require.ensure([ ], ( require ) => {
    let myModule = require( './superMyModule.js' );
    myModule.on("loadResource", myCallback)
  })
```

Comment: By replacing the require() calls with require.ensure([]) calls within the Module, it would lead to a separation of files / modules which in turn would require the browser to transfer each file individually over the wire. That is exactly what I want to avoid respectively the reason why I use a module loader like webpack in the first place.
The question was as yo correctly spotted: How to transfer the module as whole chunk (minimal overhead) but deploy those asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can offload the main thread and avoid blocking using the worker loader.

Downside: there's extra message passing to do between main window and the worker.

https://github.com/webpack/worker-loader

You can also try emmitting load events in the large module to track more granular progress.

Further reference:

- MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API
- Browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to kick off loading asynchronous JavaScript bundle through `require.ensure` as well as other Promises, here is how you can achieve that:

```
const requireEnsurePromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  require.ensure(['./modulePath'], function (requireEnsure) {
    console.log('The module is fetched but not evaluated yet');
    resolve(requireEnsure.bind(null, require.resolve('./modulePath')));
  });
});

Promise.all([
  fetch('/api/relevant/stuff').then(response => response.json()),
  requireEnsurePromise,
]).then((values) => {
  if (values[0]) {
    // DO STUFF
  }
  console.log('right before module is evaluated');
  const evaluatedModule = values[1]();
});
```

Webpack statically determined what the module path corresponds to Webpack internal representation (could be an integer or a string). Whenever Webpack recognizes the `require.ensure([], fn)` patten, it looks at the function body of the `fn` callback and do so. In order to delay the evaluation time after fetching the JavaScript bundle in a Promise fashion, `require('./modulePath')` cannot be present inside the `require.ensure` success callback as it will evaluate the module. Webpack translates `require('./modulePath')` to something like `__webpack_require__(2343423)`, that's why you would like to avoid using it in this scenario.